# Normalization in neural network with (x, y) output

Tags: neural-network, normalization, backpropagation

I built a backpropagation neural network to learn from a dataset that consists of 7 continuous inputs and 2 outputs (`x`, `y` coordinates). My implementation choice was to use one hidden layer with 7 neurons, but I did it in such a way that I can try different combinations of hidden layers with variable number of hidden nodes.

The error measurement is the usual mean squared error, calculated as follows:

```
MSE(x,y) = 1/N * sum((X - x)^2 + (Y - y)^2)
```

where `X` and `Y` are the target values, `x` and `y` the predictions. I also have to compute an accuracy measure which is the mean euclidean distance of each point from the target points, that's basically the same as the MSE, but the values inside `sum` get square-rooted.

The input ranges are all between the interval [-2, +2], plus some outliers.
The output coordinates have completely unrelated distributions (`x` is normally distributed while `y` is uniformly distributed). The `x` range is small (say -1, +1 from the mean) while the `y` range varies more (say -10, +10 from the mean).

The behavior I get is that the net seems to predict quite right the `y` output, while the `x` "flattens" to `y`. Ie, the `x` values get closer to the `y` values, the network doesn't adapt to predict the `x` correctly.

My initial choice was to scale both inputs/outputs as a whole to the usual (0,1) interval but that didn't lead to good results. So I then chose to standardize each feature separately with their z-score, and scale the outputs in the (0,1) interval (I am using the sigmoid activation function so (0,1) seemed about right). But then this strange behavior appeared.

So my questions are, how would you normalize such inputs/outputs? Is there a way to deal with such uncorrelated outputs? I had even thought about using two separate networks to predict one single output discarding the other, is that a good choice?

Could you also point me to some reading where output normalization is discussed? The literature talks a lot about normalizing the inputs, but no one seems to care about the outputs.

Comment: By any chance did you normalize it, since this question is of about a year ago ?

Comment: Well, it turned out that I did not have to normalize at all (or at least, the net would perform okay even without normalization). Since it was a regression task, all I had to do was using a linear activation function in the output layer. I don't know if this might be of any help for you?

Comment: I still had to normalize it using the min/max normalization which looks like its performing okay, still need to test some more. I am using a linear activation function in the output, but without the data normalized it does not perform well. Thanks anyway

Comment: From what I've learned,normalizing the outputs can cause issues when you operate on a test set. Imagine the test set is blind (ie you have just the inputs and must provide the output), how would you normalize the results of your net then? Although you can choose the min/max values you used for training, that's like injecting prior knowledge you obtained from the training data into the test data, which is not desirable. So yeah, it's a bit of a problem, but if the net is working okay like it is I can't tell you much. Just be aware of this potential issue.